# Printing the contents of a dictionary generated by user input

Tags: python

Getting back into python again after starting and then stopping about a year ago. I was just messing with dictionaries and building them dynamically with user input and within a function.

The code below works, but outputs it as the generic dictionary format, where what I'd like to do is have it output on a line by line basis with each key and value being on one line.

```
def person_info(name, age, address, employer, phone):

    name = name.strip()
    age = age.strip()
    address = address.strip()
    employer = employer.strip()
    phone = phone.strip()

    full_info = {'Name:': name, 'Age': age, 'Address': address, 'Employer': employer, 'Phone': phone}
    return full_info

while True:
    name = input('Enter Name: ')
    age = input('Enter Age: ')
    address = input('Enter Address: ')
    employer = input('Enter Employer: ')
    phone = input('Enter Phone Number: ')

    if name == 'q' or age == 'q' or address == 'q' or employer == 'q' or phone == 'q':
        print("...quitting")
        break

    else:
        person = person_info(name, age, address, employer, phone)
        print(person)
        break
```

With this I get the output as:

```
{'Name:': 'Tim', 'Age': '42', 'Address': '1111 Place Drive', 'Employer': 'Earth', 'Phone': '555'}
```

Where what I'd like is

Name: Tim

Age: 42

etc...

I know that if I had the dictionary statically defined I could just use something like

```
for key, value in full_info.items():
    print(key, value)
```

And it will give me the output I want, but with the method I'm trying it doesn't seem to work. I'm not sure if this has to do with the dictionary being defined within the function.

I'm sure there's a super simple answer for this, but I haven't been able to find it thus far.

Thanks!

Comment: Can't you just do your for-print loop in the line where you currently have `print(person)`? ie `for key, value in person.items(): print(key, value)`?

Comment: When you tried the way you describe, iterating through the dictionary items, what went wrong?

Comment: @FatihAkici

When I tried that before the code still worked but seemed to blatantly ignore it and gave me the same output. Must have been something weird I did because when I went back and tried it again it seems to half work.

Now it gives me the correct output but only after it also gives me output I don't want before it, basically printing out the input + output as well as just the output I want. It prints out "Enter Name: Tim" on one line then "Enter Age: 42" and so on. And then after that it prints what I actually want... ie "Name: Tim" with the next line being "Age: 42", etc

Comment: @mistertim Can you share that (defective?) code?

Comment: @mistertim It will of course, always print those "Enter Name" lines. Those are where Python is asking for YOUR input. If it doesn't print "Enter Name", how will Python ask for an input from you? It is a must due to the `input('Enter Name: ')` line. It prints that, and you enter your name. Then it prints "Enter Age", and you enter Y, etc. Finally it forms your `dict`, and once you apply the method I mentioned, you get your "Name: X", "Age: Y" etc printed line-by-line. So it works perfectly as it should.

Comment: @FatihAkici Yes it prints them out when asking for the input, but it ALSO prints them in the output so when the program is run the input asks for the name, I enter Tim. Then there's literally a line in the output after I go through all of the input queries that says "Enter Name: Tim". So in the output it prints out the question as well as the answer I gave. Then after all of that it actually prints out just the answers that were input.

Comment: @mistertim I'll post an answer explaining what's going on

Comment: Did my answer help? Let me know if it is inconsistent with what you are seeing.

Answer (score 0):

Iterating through the dictionary's items seem to work, try this and tell me if it solves your problem

```
def person_info(name, age, address, employer, phone):

    name = name.strip()
    age = age.strip()
    address = address.strip()
    employer = employer.strip()
    phone = phone.strip()

    full_info = {'Name:': name, 'Age:': age, 'Address:': address, 'Employer:': employer, 'Phone:': phone}
    return full_info

while True:
    name = input('Enter Name: ')
    age = input('Enter Age: ')
    address = input('Enter Address: ')
    employer = input('Enter Employer: ')
    phone = input('Enter Phone Number: ')

    if name == 'q' or age == 'q' or address == 'q' or employer == 'q' or phone == 'q':
        print("...quitting")
        break

    else:
        person = person_info(name, age, address, employer, phone)
        for key, value in person.items():
            print(key, value)

        break
```

Output seems to be in the format that you want using this

Comment: Thanks, that's what I recently tried as well but it gave me odd output, as I mentioned in my comment above. It now prints it out in the correct format, but instead of just printing the output ("Name: Tim" ,etc) per line, it first prints the input argument as well as the output ("Enter Name: Tim", etc), and then it prints the correct output. Really weird.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see where those confusing prints are coming from. First, I'll take your code, suppress your `print(person)` line. See what only the `input()` functions do:

```
def person_info(name, age, address, employer, phone):

    name = name.strip()
    age = age.strip()
    address = address.strip()
    employer = employer.strip()
    phone = phone.strip()

    full_info = {'Name:': name, 'Age': age, 'Address': address, 'Employer': employer, 'Phone': phone}
    return full_info

while True:
    name = input('Enter Name: ')
    age = input('Enter Age: ')
    address = input('Enter Address: ')
    employer = input('Enter Employer: ')
    phone = input('Enter Phone Number: ')

    if name == 'q' or age == 'q' or address == 'q' or employer == 'q' or phone == 'q':
        print("...quitting")
        break

    else:
        person = person_info(name, age, address, employer, phone)
        # print(person) NOTICE: This is commented out for now.
        break
```

Here is the output of this version:

```
Enter Name: a

Enter Age: b

Enter Address: c

Enter Employer: d

Enter Phone Number: e
```

It just asks me, by printing to my screen, what name/age/address/employer/phone I want to enter. When I type a/b/c/d/e, those are displayed on the screen as well, because I typed them. No further print at all for this version.

Now let's uncomment that `print(person)` line. Now, **in addition to what we just saw**, the `person` must be printed. So un-comment that, and run your code as is, you'll get this:

```
Enter Name: a

Enter Age: b

Enter Address: c

Enter Employer: d

Enter Phone Number: e
{'Name:': 'a', 'Age': 'b', 'Address': 'c', 'Employer': 'd', 'Phone': 'e'}
```

Notice, the only addition is the dictionary. The first "Enter something" lines are exactly the same as before, solely due to you asking those `input`s. That's it. It doesn't print anything more, or anything unexpected.

There is no way to hide those `Enter Name: a / Enter Age: b` prints. You can, however, edit the last dictionary. For that you just need to modify the `print(person)` into:

```
for key, value in person.items(): print(key, value)
```

Now the output becomes:

```
Enter Name: a

Enter Age: b

Enter Address: c

Enter Employer: d

Enter Phone Number: e
Name: a
Age b
Address c
Employer d
Phone e
```

Again, the first 5 prints of `Enter Name: a / Enter Age: b etc`, and then your re-formatted `person` dictionary. Again, nothing more is printed, nothing unexpected.

Hope this clarifies everything.